# Confusion over the Java .contains() method

Tags: java

For my AP CompSci project, I need to write a chatbot.

For the first step, it needs to detect certain keywords, and respond appropriately

However, even the `statement` argument doesn't contain "no", `responce` somehow always ends up set to "Why so Negative?". I have no clue why this is happeneing, but I imagine it's related to the java `contains()` method that I'm using

my code is listed below

```
static String[] family = {"mother", "father", "brother", "sister"};
static String[] pets = {"cat", "dog", "parrot", "lizard"};

static String[] family = {"mother", "father", "brother", "sister"};
static String[] pets = {"cat", "dog", "parrot", "lizard"};

public static String getResponse(String statement) {
    String response = "Interesting. Tell me more.";

    for (int i = 0; i < family.length; i++) {
        if (statement.contains(family[i])) {
            response = "Tell me more about your family.";
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pets.length; i++) {
        if (statement.contains(pets[i])) {
            response = "Tell me more about your pets.";
        }
    }

    if (statement.contains("no")); {
        response = "Why so negative?";
    }

    return response;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(getResponse("yes"));
    //This will still act like the input is "no"
}
```

I apologize about horrible formatting, I'm not great with StackOverflow

All help is appreciated - I have no clue why it's not outputting "Interesting, tell me more" like it should be

Thanks!

Comment: Your code isn't listed below. Have you tried reading the javadoc? Here is the relevant link for String#contains(...) http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-

Comment: Please post the code

Comment: I apologize about not posting the code - I accidentally submitted the question to early. The code is there now, thanks!

Comment: Your `if`-body is empty (superfluous semicolon).

Comment: I didn't even realize that, I should edit it again - any input will act as if it contains "no". I'll change the code example to have an input that doesn't have a "no" in it

Comment: if you are looking for the first keyword match, you should stopped the matching once you got the first one, otherwise the response will be overridden if the statement contains multiple keywords, for example : my cat is not at home, will always give you why so negative

Answer (score 3):

You have a semi-colon after your if statement:

```
if (statement.contains("no"));
{
    response = "Why so negative?";
}
```

This means the body of the if block is empty, i.e. is equivalent to the following code:

```
if (statement.contains("no")) {
}

{
    response = "Why so negative?";
}
```

Remove the semi-colon and it should work as you expect.